# change HTML image based on javascript value

Tags: javascript, html

First like to say I upload those as I work on it at http://ali-hassan.info
I have a table, when I click an item in the table it updates in an array for that cell, so when the page loads the cells variable is 0, when clicked it changes to 1, when that occurs I'd like for the image to change for that one cell, at the moment I have it as this in my javascript, there is a function that actually changes the cell's variable to 1.

```
function changeImage()
{
element=document.getElementById('myimage')
if (element.src.match("empty"))
  {
  element.src="1.gif";
  }
else
  {
  element.src="2.gif";
  }
}
```

And this is a sample of the HTML table

```
<td><div align="center">A</div></td>
   <td class='n' id='a1' onclick="myFunction(1,0)"><img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage(1)"  src="empty.gif"/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a2' onclick="myFunction(2,0)"><img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage(2)"  src="empty.gif"/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a3' onclick="myFunction(3,0)"><img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage(3)"  src="empty.gif"/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a4' onclick="myFunction(4,0)"><img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage(4)"  src="empty.gif"/></td>
   <td></td>
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: Yes, "when I click an item in the table it updates in an array for that cell, so when the page loads the cells variable is 0, when clicked it changes to 1, when that occurs I'd like for the image to change for that one cell"

Comment: I want to be able to treat each cell differently in that function

Answer (score 1):

```
 //modify ur js like this
 function changeImage(img)
 {
 //"img" is the image on which user clicked
 if (img.src.match("empty"))
   {
   img.src="1.gif";
   }
 else
   {
   img.src="2.gif";
   }
 }
//and html like this
  <td><div align="center">A</div></td>
  <td class='n' id='a1' onclick="myFunction(1,0)"><img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage(this)"  src="empty.gif"/></td>
  <td class='n' id='a2' onclick="myFunction(2,0)"><img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage(this)"  src="empty.gif"/></td>
  <td class='n' id='a3' onclick="myFunction(3,0)"><img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage(this)"  src="empty.gif"/></td>
  <td class='n' id='a4' onclick="myFunction(4,0)"><img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage(this)"  src="empty.gif"/></td>
  <td>
 </td>
```

You cannot use repeated Id as a selector in HTML, and it is a bad programming style

Answer (score 0):

```
<img onclick="changeImage.call(this, 1)"
```

JS:

```
function changeImage(i)
{
    this.src= i + ".gif";
}
```

Note: your example needs some changes, I only show how it's done